# ответ Ping в zabbix

Tags: linux, ping, zabbix

Добрый день. Нужно в заббикс выводить график доступности хоста путем его пинга. Комманду предпологаю такую:

```
ping -s 991 -M do 1.2.3.4
```

Меня интересует время ответа. Как бы это реализовать в заббикс.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В заббиксе есть стандартный функционал определения задержек и потерь через icmp – https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/ru/manual/config/items/itemtypes/simple_checks

Comment: человечище где ты был всё это время. Я уже это нашел и сделал.

Answer (score 1):

для определения времени работы программы можно, например, воспользоваться программой *gnu/time*:

```
$ /usr/bin/time ping -q -c 1 archive.org 2>&1 | sed -rn '/elapsed/s/.* ([^ ]+)elapsed.*/\1/p'
0:00.20
```

полный путь указан для того, чтобы избежать запуска встроенной в большинство *shell*-ов функции *time*, схожего назначения, но с весьма различающимся в разных *shell*-ах выводом, что делает её малоподходящей для автоматизации.

в любом случае при выполнении `ping` важно указывать количество пакетов (опция `-c`), иначе программа `ping` будет работать бесконечно.

---

дополнительная информация:

```
$ man ping
$ man time
$ help time
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Решил сделать через Fping.
fping -q -c 1 ya.ru 2>&1 | cut -d'/' -f8
Так получаю выхлоп пинга, как сюда добавить ещё значение loss?

Comment: Либо awk либо sed. Хочу получать 2 значения.